# MPI send results to other processes

Tags: c, mpi

This program , divides a bidimensional array ,make some operations with the chunk of rows assigned to  every process, but I don't know how to send the results to mix it and get the complete  result on the complete array,there is any simple way to combine the results of every process?I thought some solution but are too complex ,I could be useful if anyone knows a simple solution.

```
  #include "mpi.h"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <sys/time.h>

  #define N 12
  #define ITERS 10
  #define ARRAY_SIZE (N+2) * (N+2)

  double **A;

  void initialize (double **A)
  {
    int i,j;

     for(i =0; i < N+2 ; i++){
       for(j =0; j < N+2 ; j++){
        if(i== 0 || j == 0 || i == (N+1) || j == (N +1) )
          A[i][j] = 0.0;
        else
          A[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
       }
     }
  }
  void showArray(double **A){
    int i,j;
    printf("\n");
    for(i =0 ; i < N+2 ; i++){
      for(j =0; j < N+2 ; j++){
        printf("%f, ",A[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }



  void stencil(double **A, int inicio, int final){
    int i = inicio;
    int j;
    for(i; i <= final; i++){
      for(j =1; j <= N ; j++){
          A[i][j] = 0.3 *( A[i][j] + A[i-1][j] + A[i+1][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i][j+1]);
      }
    }
  }


  int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int rank, size,tag=1;
    char msg='A';
    double row;
    MPI_Status status;
    double *result_row;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int n_per_proc = N/size;

    printf("Process # %d started \n", rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    A = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double *));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N+2; i++) {
      A[i] = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double));
    }

    initialize(A);
    //showArray(A);
    int inicio = n_per_proc * rank +1;
    int final = n_per_proc * (rank+1);

    if(rank == size-1)
      final = N;

    /*printf("rank = %d inicio = %d\n",rank, inicio );
    printf("rank = %d final = %d\n",rank, final );
    printf("%s\n");*/
    stencil(A, inicio,final);
    showArray(A);

    printf("Finishing proc %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();

  }
```

Comment: Have you considered `MPI_Scatter()` and `MPI_Gather()` ?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to place the result received on MPI_Gather on the right place of the result array(sorry if its a noob question)

Comment: As explained [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.1/man3/MPI_Gather.3.php), in MPI_Gather, the root process receives and stores the messages from the processes in rank order. For example, if you have only 3 processes, and rank0 sends `{a0, a1, a2}`, rank1 sends `{b0, b1, b2}`, and rank2 sends `{c0, c1, c2}`, then the root receives `{a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, c0, c1, c2}`.

Comment: an other option is to manually specify where the data should be received to / sent from with the `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Gatherv()` variants.